# Google App Script Optimization for Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Got 2 pretty simple scripts;

```
  function deleteFormulas() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Social");
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Marchex - Calls");

  sh0.getRange("T3:AE").clearContent();
  sh1.getRange("F3:L").clearContent();

  }

function copyFormulas() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Social");
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Marchex - Calls");

  sh0.getRange("T2:AE2").autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  sh1.getRange("F2:L2").autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

They time out. Only have 500 rows. Formulas are Sumifs, countifs, and simple math operations. Any way to make it script cleaner or is it up to the formulas within google sheets.

Comment: If you only run it on 4-5 rows does it work or does it timeout also?

Comment: Timeout.

Have I reached a limit? I don't really understand them.

Comment: You say "They time out. " in your question. What do you mean by that? google scripts have a limit of 6min if I remember well, a function lasting more than that wil automatically stop if it reatches that time.

Comment: "Service using too much computer time for one day" - not entirely sure, guessing it's because the formulas in google sheets are slow.

"Exceeded maximum execution time" - which I guess uses up the 6 minutes. Though to delete 500 rows with clearcontent(), it's kind of ridiculous.

Comment: You also have an execution time limit for one day, you might have run too long function too much time in your tests. Even if your code doesn't take 6 min anymore you won't be able to run anything today. The formulas have nothing to do with the execution time, if you simply try again tomorrow it should be working perfectly.

Comment: Any way to overcome this manually or is it a hard limit?

Comment: Sadly it is a hard limit, I also have tried to overcome it and never found how.

Comment: Please read about the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), you might be hitting one of those, especially if you are using custom functions.

Comment: Yeah, all custom functions. 30 Seconds. Damn. :(